# Flask implementing ? for argument rather than /

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to implement redirection to take my users back to their previous page when he chooses a specific language on the menu bar.

I have this function:

```
@application.route('/locale/<locale>/redirect_to/<redirect_to>/', methods=['GET'])
def set_locale(locale, redirect_to):
  session['locale'] = locale
  return redirect(redirect_to)     # Change this to previous url
```

right now I have this for my language options:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li><a href="{{ url_for("set_locale", locale="en", redirect_to=request.path) }}">English</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ url_for("set_locale", locale="es", redirect_to=request.path) }}">Spanish</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, i keep running into errors because request.path is in the format of /some/url/like/this/ and it keeps messing up the redirect_to argument where I can getting errors like path undefined etc.

Traditionally, developers have used `?redirect_to=/home` to get around this problem. However, I don't know if there's a proper way to implement the ?key=value pattern in flask without making it so patchy that it will break when I change things up.

How could I implement the ?key=value pattern easily here?

Comment: why don't you use request.referrer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any keyword arguments passed to `url_for` that aren't part of the route will be included in the query string.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('set_locale', locale='en', redirect_to=request.path) }}">
```

Your endpoint then changes to something similar to

```
@application.route('/locale/<locale>/')
def set_locale(locale):
    session['locale'] = locale
    redirect_to = request.args.get('redirect_to', '/')
    return redirect(redirect_to)
```

The trade off is that you can't enforce `redirect_to` in the route so you need to handle that yourself. Here I defaulted to `'/'`. Another approach would be

```
redirect_to = request.args['redirect_to']
```

If `redirect_to` isn't included in the query string, this would result in Flask returning a 400 bad request response.

Comment: Did you mean `request.args.get('redirect_to', '/')`? Works thanks

Comment: Yeah. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Path should help in this case:

`@application.route('/locale/<locale>/redirect_to/<path:redirect_to>/')`

It allows redirect_to to take on a /some/url/like/this/ path.

Comment: Not sure if that really works: On my webpage I see: `http://localhost:5000/locale/en/redirect_to//home/` as the link to click once I click it I still get: `404 Not found`

Comment: flask is not able to redirect /locale/en/redirect_to//home/ to `application.route('/locale/<locale>/redirect_to/<path:redirect_to>/', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: http://localhost:5000/locale/en/redirect_to/home/ works for me. If you need the link to be http://localhost:5000/locale/en/redirect_to//home/ you could use the route @application.route('/locale/<locale>/redirect_to//<path:redirect_to>/', methods=["GET"])